# Updated xcode, no longer able to compile phonegap

Tags: iphone, xcode, mobile, cordova

I updated xcode and now I am no longer able to compile my PhoneGap project. Any insight on how to fix this would be greatly appriciated. Below is the output from console.log:

```
2012-09-25 14:52:16.309 PhoneGapTest[18978:c07] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2012-09-25 14:52:16.323 PhoneGapTest[18978:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught     exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]:     object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x143012 0x257ce7e 0xf6b6a 0xf6a20 0x1696d 0x5bb81 0x341d 0x45f817 0x45f882 0x3aea25    0x3aedbf 0x3aef55 0x3b7f67 0x2ef7 0x37b7b7 0x37bda7 0x37cfab 0x38e315 0x38f24b 0x380cf8     0x33aedf9 0x33aead0 0xb8bf5 0xb8962 0xe9bb6 0xe8f44 0xe8e1b 0x37c7da 0x37e65c 0x27d6 0x2705)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 3):

That's a compile error? If it is a runtime error (that's what it looks like), you are trying to insert a nil object into an array, that's what's causing the error. Add a general exception breakpoint to your project to figure out where that's happening. To do this with Xcode 4:

- Click on the Breakpoints symbol in the Navigator pane
- Click the + button at the bottom of the pane
- Select "Add Exception Breakpoint".

If it is a compile error, do a project wide find on "insertObject:" and check if you are trying to do "insertObject:nil"

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if I'm having the same problem as the original author, but this advice has helped me a lot.